# Fontawesome icons is not loading in IE11

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack-2, typescript2.1

I am working in a angular2 application and i am using `"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",` while loading the application in IE11 the font-awesome icons is not loading in IE. I have imported the font-awesome files in vendor.ts file

```
import 'font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

And i have use meta tag in index.html

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11"> 

angular v2.4.10
webpack v2.2.1
Typescript v2.2.1
Node v7.2.1
```

Comment: Is this only related to your project?  Can you see font awesome icons on their site in IE11?  Can you see other font based icons like glyphicons in IE11 or in your project in IE11?

Comment: @ppovoski font awesome icons are related to primeng datatable. And I am using @angular/material  icons in my project and it's loading in IE11.